# Passing prop to react component for customised MUI tooltip value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I am trying to display a custom value to tooltip within MUI

Tooltip API: https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/#css

The tooltip is being used with slider and therefore value of 1,2,3, etc is being displayed in tooltip fine but I need to translate this integer values into a meaningful value.

Therefore I need to pass a prop (that is an object) which contains the map of what these values. i.e. representing 1 = London, 2 = Barcelona, etc

I am trying to pass a prop to ValueLabelComponent in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/h0esn?file=/demo.js:432-651

Is it possible to pass props value to this component?, if so how?

```
  <Slider
    ValueLabelComponent={ValueLabelComponent}
    aria-label="custom thumb label"
    defaultValue={20}
  />

function ValueLabelComponent(props) {
  //need custom prop value here
  const { children, open, value } = props;

  return (
    <Tooltip open={open} enterTouchDelay={500} placement="bottom" title=. {'test value'}>
      {children}
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi! can you explain more? what kind of props do you want to pass to the `ValueLabelComponent` function?

Comment: @alisasani Edited the answer with some more details, the prop will be an object which would contain a map representing 1 = London, 2 = Barcelona, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any props you want to the `ValueLabelComponent` func as below:

```
ValueLabelComponent={(props) =>
          ValueLabelComponent(
            props,
            props.value < 20 ? "smaller than 20" : "bigger than 20"
          )
        }
```

Then these values can be used in the function to show the meaning of those values in the tooltip:

```
function ValueLabelComponent(props, map) {
  const { children, open, value } = props;
  return (
    <Tooltip open={open} enterTouchDelay={0} placement="top" title={map}>
      {children}
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-g0o00?file=/demo.js:429-638)